# Input radio switching div in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, radio-button, checked

I know i can switch div show/hide just that simple:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br />
<div class="check-element animate-show-hide" ng-show="checked">
  I show up when your checkbox is checked.
</div>
```

when the input type is checkbox. But I would like to have two input type radio and switch two divs show/hide.

```
<input type="radio" name="same" />
<input type="radio" name="same" />
```

How to achieve that? Working example would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="radio" name="same" ng-model="checked" value="true" />
<input type="radio" name="same" ng-model="checked" value="false" />
<div class="check-element animate-show-hide" ng-show="checked=='true'">
  I show up when your checkbox is checked.
</div>
```

Comment: Not working correctly https://plnkr.co/edit/Rg92yvGhTTE4wXgk92dL?p=preview

Comment: Ohh, some mistake in my typo i use single equal in ng-show, i have updated my code, working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8PaykKK2GFexEQDlZKMh?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! How can i add so the very first input would be checked when page is loaded first time? I tried by simple adding "checked" at the end of <input ... /> but it doesnt make it checked in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried this?

```
<input type="radio" name="showDiv" ng-model="checked1"><br />
<input type="radio" name="showDiv" ng-model="checked2"><br />

<div class="check-element animate-show-hide" ng-show="checked">
  I show up when your checkbox1 is checked.
</div>
<div class="check-element animate-show-hide" ng-show="checked2">
  I show up when your checkbox2 is checked.
</div>
```

Or do you want something specific?

Comment: Yes i do not want to have two divs shown at the same time thats why i want to use input type="radio" instead of checkboxes. So with the same name attrubut they will never be checked together at the same time. And i want to show div1 when input type radio number 1 is checked and show div2 when input type radio number 2 is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.checked = 'true'; 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">

<input type="radio" ng-model="checked" value="true"> true
<input type="radio" ng-model="checked" value="false">false
<div class="check-element animate-show-hide" ng-show="checked">
  I show up when your checkbox is checked.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like I wrote before i do not want to be able to check 2 inputs at the same time that's why I ask how to achieve that with input type = RADIO instead of checkboxes.